# Using DTOs properly in a Restful web service

Tags: java, spring, rest, oop

I am developing a restful web service using spring framework. I have a few questions on how to use DTOs properly in my project.

First of all, I saw a lot of code examples on using DTOs and there is always a one to one mapping with entities. For `User` entity we have `UserDto`, For `Country`, we have `CountryDto` and etc. I think this is not flexible at all. For every service, I need two DTOs for input and output. is that ok?

If I define two DTOs for each service, Can I name them with request and response suffixes? For example for `createUser` service, I have two DTO objects called `CreateUserRequest` and `CreateUserResponse`.

Some services have no outputs(Just a status code) or inputs(Just an Id in URL). Should I Define an empty DTO for them or not? If I don't define a DTO in these scenarios, it is a bit confusing because sometimes you define two DTOs for service and sometimes just one.

Should I map path variables like `/users/{id}` to DTO objects too? for example instead of:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id)
```

do something like:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity getUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") GetUserRequest request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this pattern :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable long id) {
        ResponseEntity<User> response = null;
        try {
            User user = userService.getUser(id);
            response = new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
            response = new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Don't create a url like this : `/users/{id}`

Create a url like this - `/{id}` - this will give more abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

In the ideal restful web service you manipulate **resources** with properties, not request-response structures. So, if you create User, it's ok to accept and return the same DTO and the method looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user)
```

Using request body for GET is technically possible, but de-facto is deprecated, use path variables and request params.

> Some services have no outputs(Just a status code) or inputs(Just an Id in URL). Should I Define an empty DTO for them or not?

No, you should not define DTO for objects that you do not have.

And the last detail: if you have multiple methods manipulating same resource (e.g. User), do not make multiple User DTOs for get, post, etc.